# How to open a single tweet in a separate tab with a single click?

Tags: twitter

Currently if I want to open a tweet in a separate tab (usually so I can read the replies later), I have to:

- Click the tweet
- Go to the URL bar in my browser
- Copy the URL
- Open a new tab
- Paste URL and enter
- Go back to previous tab
- Click the "back" arrow to get back to the feed

It'd be easier if there each tweet had an `<a>` tag I could middle-click with my mouse's scrollbar to open in a separate tab, but there is none.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Ya, I really hate the fact that I can't right click and open in new window! I don't want to lose my place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy one-click opening of a tweet in separate tab:

1. **Locate the date/time stamp of the desired tweet**

[image]

2. **Click it with the scroll-wheel of your mouse**

[image]

Comment: Note that this works on a normal tweet in the feed, but *not* for the date/time stamp for a tweet being quoted. If you hover your mouse over the date/time stamp for a quoted tweet, it is not underlined and there is no right-clickable link.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's possible to middle-click the timestamp:

[image]